# Rails UJS not firing with Rails 7

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, rails-ujs

I upgraded my Rails application to Rails 7. I know that Turbolinks and Rails UJS actually are replaced by the Hotwire combination of Stimulus and Turbo in Rails 7, but I wanted to know whether I can still use UJS and if yes, why is it not working?

My method that is not working looks like this:

```
  submit(event) {
    this.errorTarget.classList.add("hidden")
    Rails.fire(this.formTarget, "submit")
    console.log('hi')
  }
```

The console.log works. When I click on an element, it used to change with this code, but now it doesn't change anymore. `Rails.fire` simply does not fire anymore and there is no error in the log or in the network part when I inspect the website.

I feel like I am missing something crucial here, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 34):

To add rails-ujs to Rails 7 you should to do following steps:

1. Pin it, to let the application know, which package to use. Enter in bash:

```sh
./bin/importmap pin @rails/ujs
```

And now you have in your **config/importmap.rb** file something like this:

```rb
pin "@rails/ujs", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@rails/ujs@7.0.1/lib/assets/compiled/rails-ujs.js"
```

2. Now include @rails/ujs to your javascript. In file **javascript/controllers/application.js** add:

```js
import Rails from '@rails/ujs';

Rails.start();
```

3. Restart your application server

Comment: You might want to use `./bin/importmap pin @rails/ujs@7` to pin it to version 7. Otherwise you might end up loading @rails/ujs@6 at the moment.

Comment: If you don't want to use the javascript CDN in production you can do:
`./bin/importmap pin @rails/ujs --download`. This will put an entry into your config/importmap.rb file that looks like this instead: `pin "@rails/ujs", to: "@rails--ujs.js"`

Comment: As of now it does pull in ujs 7

Comment: Doesn’t have to be `javascript/controllers/application.js`, works in `javascript/application.js` as well.

Answer (score 1):

The prolem is that in Rails 6.x the form was generated automatically with the attribute `data-remote="true"` while this does not happen anymore after an upgrade to Rails 7.x.

To get back the old behavior and to have your `Rails.fire` call working again, you need to explicitly add `data-remote="true"` to the form.

Answer (score -1):

As [coorasse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75410391/480304) already pointed out, `form_with` used to implement `remote: true` by default. This changed with Rails 7.x (or even since 6.1 I think).

Fortunately, instead of manually adjusting all forms, the default setting can also be changed back explicitly. Here's what helped in my case, convenient and easy:

**config/application.rb**

```
config.action_view.form_with_generates_remote_forms = true
```

Comment: Works like a charm