Remote modal not rendering validation errors on file upload - Ruby on Rails
I have a custom validation to accept only PDF on active storage attachment. I have tried to upload non-PDF file to see the errors on the form(remote modal) but on the logs it shows Missing Partial, it seems like its looking for :new => format: {:html}.
BTW, I tried to use a non-remote form and the validation error shows up. I was expecting to show validation errors in remote modal form.
Here's my code.
Controller
def create
  @employee = HrmModule::Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
  @attachment_type = ::HrmModule::AttachmentType.find(params[:attachment_type_id])
  @attachment = @employee.attachments.new(attachment_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @attachment.save
      format.html { redirect_to hrm_module_employee_attachments_url(employee_id: @employee.id), notice: 'Attachment saved!' }
      format.js { redirect_to hrm_module_employee_attachments_url(employee_id: @employee.id), notice: 'Attachment saved!' }
    else
      format.js { render :new, content_type: 'text/javascript' }
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: {errors: @attachment.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

new.js.erb
$("#remote-modal").find(".modal-dialog")
$("#remote-modal").find(".modal-content").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'new', remote: true) %>");
$("#remote-modal").modal();

_new.html.erb
<div class="modal-header">
  <h5 class="modal-title">New Attachment</h5>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
<% remote ||= false %>
<%= simple_form_for @attachment, html: { autocomplete: "off" }, remote: true, url: hrm_module_employee_attachments_path(employee_id: @employee.id, attachment_type_id: @attachment_type.id), method: :post do |f| %>
  <%= render 'form', f: f %>
<% end %>

_form.html.erb
<div class="modal-body">
  <h5><%= @attachment_type.name_and_alias %></h5>
  <%= f.input :attachment_type_id, input_html: {class: 'form-control', value: @attachment_type.id}, as: :hidden %>
  <% if @attachment_type.others? %>
    <%= f.input :name, label: 'Attachment Name', input_html: {class: 'form-control'} %>
  <% end %>
  <% if @attachment_type.frequently? %>
    <%= f.input :year, label: 'Calendar Year', collection: [Date.today.year].to_a.reverse.map{|y| [y, Date.new(y.to_i)]}, input_html: {class: "form-control"}, selected: Date.today.year %>
  <% end %>
  <% if @attachment_type.ipcr_opcr? %>
    <%= f.input :semester, label: 'Semester', collection: ::HrmModule::Attachment.semesters.keys.to_a.map{|s| [s.titleize, s]}, input_html: {class: "form-control"} %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.input :document, label: "Attach Document (Scanned PDF)", input_html: {class: "form-control"}, as: :file, accept: 'application/pdf' %>

  <%= link_to "Delete Attachment", hrm_module_employee_attachment_path(employee_id: @employee.id, id: @attachment.id), class: "btn btn-outline-danger", method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} if @attachment.persisted? %>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-outline-success float-right", data: { disable_with: "Processing..." } %>
</div>

Terminal log
Started POST "/hrm_module/employees/957a3b96-411c-46de-a057-01d827d63853/attachments?attachment_type_id=73d96912-daaa-4994-b142-a25869389571" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-06-07 09:41:47 +0800
Processing by HrmModule::Employees::AttachmentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"hrm_module_attachment"=>{"attachment_type_id"=>"73d96912-daaa-4994-b142-a25869389571", "year"=>"2024-01-01", "semester"=>"first_semester", "document"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fbfea3c5418 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20240607-6191-hyjlcg.pdf>, @content_type="application/pdf", @original_filename="CSC Resolution No. 1800692.pdf", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"hrm_module_attachment[document]\"; filename=\"CSC Resolution No. 1800692.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Save", "attachment_type_id"=>"73d96912-daaa-4994-b142-a25869389571", "employee_id"=>"957a3b96-411c-46de-a057-01d827d63853"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "a9919900-92cd-4cd9-92a0-ac1fb448ab29"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  HrmModule::Employee Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees" WHERE "employees"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "957a3b96-411c-46de-a057-01d827d63853"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/hrm_module/employees/attachments_controller.rb:21:in `create'
  HrmModule::Settings::AttachmentType Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "attachment_types".* FROM "attachment_types" WHERE "attachment_types"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "73d96912-daaa-4994-b142-a25869389571"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/hrm_module/employees/attachments_controller.rb:22:in `create'
  CACHE HrmModule::Settings::AttachmentType Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "attachment_types".* FROM "attachment_types" WHERE "attachment_types"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "73d96912-daaa-4994-b142-a25869389571"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/hrm_module/employees/attachments_controller.rb:25:in `block in create'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 101ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms | Allocations: 16988)


  
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template hrm_module/employees/attachments/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :prawn, :jbuilder, :axlsx]}.

Searched in:
  * "/home/neu/lgusys/app/views"
  * "/home/neu/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/simple_calendar-3.0.4/app/views"
  * "/home/neu/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/devise-4.9.4/app/views"
  * "/home/neu/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/kaminari-core-1.2.2/app/views"
  * "/home/neu/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/actiontext-7.1.3.3/app/views"
  * "/home/neu/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/actionmailbox-7.1.3.3/app/views"
):
  
app/controllers/hrm_module/employees/attachments_controller.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in create'
app/controllers/hrm_module/employees/attachments_controller.rb:24:in `create'
Finished "/cable" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-06-07 09:41:48 +0800
NotificationChannel stopped streaming from notification_channel


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70767231/rails-ujs-not-firing-with-rails-7
